# MacBook M1: ssl module in Python is not available on Conda environment, SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have created `conda` environment on my Macbook M1 with `python 3.8` using Anaconda. Whenever I am trying to install any libaries using pip getting the following error:

```
(llm) mdrahman@Mds-MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % python -m pip install --upgrade pip

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./anaconda3/envs/llm/lib/python3.8/site-packages (23.0.1)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
(llm) mdrahman@Mds-MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % pip install pandas
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

I checked the SSL in the environment:

```
(llm) mdrahman@Mds-MacBook-Pro-3 llm % ls
bin     conda-meta  include     lib     share       ssl
(llm) mdrahman@Mds-MacBook-Pro-3 llm % ls ./ssl 
cacert.pem      cert.pem        ct_log_list.cnf     ct_log_list.cnf.dist    misc            openssl.cnf     openssl.cnf.dist
```

```
(llm) mdrahman@Mds-MacBook-Pro-3 llm % conda install -c anaconda openssl

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: Why did you vote -1? curious to know.